# transform between unitary operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If I have a unitary operator $\exp(i\phi X)$, where $X$ is hermitian and $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$, is there a known way of finding an operator $\hat Y$ such that $$\exp(i\phi \hat X)=\exp(if(\phi) \hat Y)$$
for a given $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only happen if $f(\phi)=a\phi$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, differentiating the identity $$e^{i\phi X}=e^{if(\phi)Y}$$ at $\phi=0$ we get that $X=f'(0)Y$, so $e^{if(\phi) Y}=e^{i\phi f'(0) Y}$ for all $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $f(\phi)=f'(0)\phi$.

In this case, trivially, $Y=X/{f'(0)}$ is the change of operators you are looking for.